# SQLiteLog Error (1) near "INSERT": syntax error

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to read and execute an SQL script from a file. CREATE commands work but my first INSERT command results in a Logcat error with tag "SQLiteLog" and text "(1) near "INSERT": syntax error". The error is thrown on the database.execSQL() line.

```
String[] createScript = outputStream.toString().split(";");
            for (int i = 0; i < createScript.length; i++) {
                String sqlStatement = createScript[i].trim();
                // TODO You may want to parse out comments here
                if (sqlStatement.length() > 0) {
                    database.execSQL(sqlStatement + ";");
                }
            }
```

The SQL line is as follows

```
INSERT INTO [EntityAttributeSet] ([Id],[Code]) VALUES (1,NULL);
```

The CREATE statement is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [EntityAttributeSet] ([Id] int IDENTITY (636,1) NOT NULL, [Code]nvarchar(50) NULL);
```

Hex dump of a few INSERT statements:

```
0000-0c00:  20 4e 4f 54-20 4e 55 4c-4c 0d 0a 29-3b 0d 0a 49  .NOT.NUL L..);..I
0000-0c10:  4e 53 45 52-54 20 49 4e-54 4f 20 5b-45 6e 74 69  NSERT.IN TO.[Enti
0000-0c20:  74 79 41 74-74 72 69 62-75 74 65 53-65 74 5d 20  tyAttrib uteSet].
0000-0c30:  28 5b 49 64-5d 2c 5b 43-6f 64 65 5d-29 20 56 41  ([Id],[C ode]).VA
0000-0c40:  4c 55 45 53-20 28 31 2c-4e 55 4c 4c-29 3b 0d 0a  LUES.(1, NULL);..
0000-0c50:  0d 0a 49 4e-53 45 52 54-20 49 4e 54-4f 20 5b 45  ..INSERT .INTO.[E
0000-0c60:  6e 74 69 74-79 41 74 74-72 69 62 75-74 65 53 65  ntityAtt ributeSe
0000-0c70:  74 5d 20 28-5b 49 64 5d-2c 5b 43 6f-64 65 5d 29  t].([Id] ,[Code])
0000-0c80:  20 56 41 4c-55 45 53 20-28 32 2c 4e-55 4c 4c 29  .VALUES. (2,NULL)
0000-0c90:  3b 0d 0a 0d-0a 49 4e 53-45 52 54 20-49 4e 54 4f  ;....INS ERT.INTO
```

Comment: remove the `";"` part

Comment: There are some junk characters in the string you're reading from the file, just before or after `INSERT`.

Comment: @laalto could a junk character be an empty line?

Comment: When I copy and paste the script into MS Word and search for Nonbreaking spaces nothing is found

Comment: It doesn't seem like I have any bad chars, but here is part of my hex dump: 0d 0a 49 4e-53 45 52 54-20 49 4e 54-4f 20 5b 45

Comment: Log the entire `sqlStatement`.

Comment: @CL. Added a few statements

Comment: The hex dump looks OK. Log the actual value of `sqlStatement` that you are executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem myself -- there was a command from a different flavor of SQL later in the script. Removing it fixed the error.

Answer (score -2):

if your first parameter is really an Integer do this:

```
  INSERT INTO EntityAttributeSet (Id,Code) VALUES (1,NULL)
```

If it's a **varchar** (string), do this:

```
  INSERT INTO EntityAttributeSet (Id,Code) VALUES ("1",NULL)
```

more info on: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work either. Same error occurs.

Comment: That is actually allowed per SQLlite documentation. Its originally a SQL Server thing to allow spaces and other non-standard characters in names. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: The first parameter is indeed an int.

Comment: could you show your table scheme? or at least the 'CREATE' statement? it might be the cause of the issue.